# Invalid read of size 4 incrementing size of an array

Tags: c++, arrays, valgrind

i'm having 4 errors running Valgrind trying to increment an array (initially of size 10) that i use for a templated stack, valgrind gives me 4 errors when i try to add an 11th element to the array (exactly when I have to increase the dimensions during the push):

```
class stack {

private:
    int _size = 10;
    T *_data;
    int _top;
    int _count = 0;

public:

// costructor used
   stack(int s) {
       this->_size = s;
       _data = new T[_size];
       this->_top = -1;

   }

   ....

   void push(T v) {
        if (_count <= _size) {

        this->_top++;
        this->_data[_top] = v;  
        this->_count++;
       }else{
        //HEAP ERRORS HERE ++++++++
        _size++;
        T *temp = new T[_size];
         for(int i = 0; i < _top; i++) {
            temp[i] = _data[i];
        }
        delete [] _data;
        _data=temp;
        _data[_top] = v;        
        this->_top++;
        this->_count++;         
    }
```

I'm not sure about the new operator and the delete[] after the else statement, I think I'm having problems just there but i couldn't figure out another way to solve it.

In main.cpp i only push 11 elements in the templated stack:

```
stack<int> s;
s.push(1);
s.push(2);
s.push(3);
s.push(4);
s.push(5);
s.push(6);
s.push(7);
s.push(8);
s.push(9);
s.push(10);
s.push(11);
```

this is valgrind's output

```
 ==4178== Invalid write of size 4
 ==4178==    at 0x10921E: stack<int>::push(int) (stack.h:85)
 ==4178==    by 0x108ED2: main (main.cpp:32)
 ==4178==  Address 0x5b82ca8 is 0 bytes after a block of size 
 40 alloc'd
 ==4178==    at 0x4C3089F: operator new[](unsigned long) (in 
 /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
 ==4178==    by 0x109144: stack<int>::stack() (stack.h:28)
 ==4178==    by 0x108B8D: main (main.cpp:9)
  HEAP SUMMARY:
 ==4178==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
 ==4178==   total heap usage: 4 allocs, 4 frees, 73,808 bytes 
 allocated
 ==4178== 
 ==4178== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
 ==4178== 
 ==4178== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
 ==4178== ERROR SUMMARY: 4 errors from 4 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 
 0)
```

Thank you.

Comment: Arrays are 0-based and include n elements not n + 1.  So `int foo[10]` is only valid for foo[0] ... foo[9] not foo[10] and this is a bug: `if (_count <= _size)`.

Comment: Please, edit your question and show a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Use containers and/or smart pointers. *Not* manual memory management (`new`/`delete`) - that stuff is error prone and mostly obsolete these days.

Comment: [OT]: `top + 1` and `count` seems to be always equal, so one seems redundant. Traditional terms are `size` and `capacity` btw.

Comment: Resizing policy is generally to multiply by a constant (`2`) to reduce amortized complexity to `O(1)`, instead of your current `O(n)`.

Comment: Just use `std::stack` and don’t waste the time.

Comment: I once introduced another index variable in order to avoid off-by-one bugs. Then I had twice as many sources for off-by-one bugs. It was not the best idea I've ever had. (Not the worst either, unfortunately.)

Comment: Use std::stack and head off early for a drink.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned by Dave S, the `if (_count <= _size)` condition is causing your heap corruption. Changing the condition to `if (_count < _size)` will result in the behavior you expect.

As it is, you will iterate from 0 to 10, for eleven total pushes before triggering overflow.

Comment: actually I tried also this condition but with that It prints _count=0 after adding the 11th element

Comment: okay I was putting _count++ after the delete statement, now it works fine. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You said 11th push causes the error. It seems the reason is the `<=`. When the `count` is equal `size` you should extend the array, but your code pushes the item past the end element.

Note, that common case is the errors on the range edges. To avoid such a things use unit tests. Also try to avoid develop things that are already done, just use one of existing.